# How to forward DNS requests from MAAS to AWS Inbound endpoint

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, maas

I am trying to access a private DNS from AWS in MAAS. I already have everything set up, including the inbound endpoint in Amazon.
I added the inbound endpoint address in "Upstream DNS used to resolve domains not managed by this MAAS", however, for some reason, it is not working. I can see that when I try to do a nslookup in the private DNS, MAAS do not show anything, but when I do a nslookup with the inbound endpoint as the DNS, it gets the right IP address.

Right now my solution was to add manually through recording a domain in MAAS. How can I do this automatically?

Comment: MAAS is not a well known acronym / product as far as I know. If you want help you should probably edit your question to explain what it is. Your description is generally a bit vague - can you expand on what / where your inbound endpoint is - are you referring to Route53 Resolver inbound endpoint? Generally you should edit to make sure your question is easily understood and make it easy to help you.

Comment: @Tim MAAS (Metal as a Service - https://maas.io/) is a service by Canonical. And yes, by inbound endpoint I mean Route53 Resolver inbound endpoint.

Comment: I've used Route53 resolver inbound endpoints to allow a corporate to delegate DNS for and ALB to AWS R53 Resolver, across multiple accounts with multiple VPCs, etc. It was quite fiddly to get working and it's not a simple thing to do. If you want help you'll have to share a LOT more information. Doing diagnostics yourself is probably going to be easier. I suggest testing locally, using VPC flow logs. I ended up talking to AWS Support to get it working. Useful blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/simplify-dns-management-in-a-multiaccount-environment-with-route-53-resolver/